# Limpiar SRC de la etiqueta Audio con Js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Cordial Saludo, lo que quiero hacer es limpiar el src de la etiqueta audio

```
<audio id="videoarea"  style="display: none;" controls="controls" src="cancion.mp3"></audio>
```

quiero que al dar click en un boton

```
<input type="button" onclick"limpiar();" value="limpiar">



<script>

function limpiar(){

//limpiar el src
}
</script>
```

espero me entiendan y me puedan ayudar, no se como realizarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con:

```
document.getElementById("videoarea").removeAttribute("src")
```

o

```
document.getElementById("videoarea").setAttribute("src", "");
```

Comment: la segunda de hecho me parece la opción que requiere el OP, pues con esa eliminas el valor del atributo, pero dicho atributo sigue estando, sin embargo la primera no la considero adecuada pues estas removiendo dicho atributo de la etiqueta

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias